# If the letters of the word $PARKAR$ are written down in all possible manner as they are in dictionary,then find the rank of the word $PARKAR.$

Tags: combinatorics

If the letters of the word $PARKAR$ are written down in all possible manner as they are in dictionary,then find the rank of the word $PARKAR.$

---

The words starting with $A$ are $\frac{5!}{2!}$
The words starting with $K$ are $\frac{5!}{2!2!}$
The words starting with $PA$ are $\frac{4!}{2!}$
The words starting with $PAA$ are $\frac{3!}{2!}$
The words starting with $PAK$ are $\frac{3!}{2!}$
The words starting with $PAR$ are $3!$
The words starting with $PARA$ are $2$
So rank of $PARKAR$ is $60+30+12+3+3+6+1=115$
But my answer is not correct.I dont know where i am wrong.

Comment: Did you mean the words starting with PARA (rather than PARK) are $2$?

Comment: $PARA$ comes before $PARK$...

Comment: Yes i corrected it,but my answer is still wrong@N.F.Taussig

Comment: You're double counting words starting with PA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that words that begin with PA include PARKAR, so you cannot count them toward the total unless you exclude those that fall after PARKAR in an alphabetical list.  You made a similar mistake when you counted words that begin with PAR.  Thus, you need to count words beginning with A, K, PAA, PAK, PARA, and PARKAR itself.

Answer (score 2):

no. of words starting with A = $\frac{5!}{2!}$

no. of words starting with K = $\frac{5!}{2!2!}$

no. of words starting with PA[fixed]A = $\frac{3!}{2!}$

no. of words starting with PA[fixed]K = $\frac{3!}{2!}$

no. of words starting with PAR[fixed]A = 2!

now next word = PARKAR - 1

Now add all these to get rank of PARKAR